# Typescript compile two directories together

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two angular apps within one directory like below,

[image]

Right now the compiler only works for the src/ folder.

```
tsc -p src/ && webpack --env=dev --progress --profile --colors
```

How can I compile both folders together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included the following into the tsconfig.json file,

```
"include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "src-charts/**/*"
    ]
```

The typescript transpiles both apps now.